Angular HttpClient observer always throws 401
I have a problem with HttpClient. When I try to send a POST request from my frontend, I always receive a 401 Unauthorized error; it doesn't even reach the endpoint. I tried entering incognito mode to see if it was a cache issue or something similar, but apparently, that's not the case, as it continues to give me the 401 error without even calling the endpoint. I also tried with Postman, and it works perfectly there.
This is my login service:
@Injectable()
export class LoginService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    if (error.status === 0) {
      // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
      console.error('An error occurred:', error.error);
    } else {
      console.log(error);
      if (error.status === 401) {
        return throwError(() => new Error('Email or password incorrect'));
      }
      // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
      // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong.
      console.error(
        `Backend returned code ${error.status}, body was: `,
        error.error
      );
    }
    // Return an observable with a user-facing error message.
    return throwError(() => new Error('Try again in another moment'));
  }

  login(userData: UserData): Observable<UserData> {
    return this.http
      .post<UserData>(
        `http://localhost:8000/api/auth/login`,
        { userData },
        { withCredentials: true }
      )
      .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
  }
}

Angular app config:
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(routes),
    provideHttpClient(withFetch()),
    importProvidersFrom(HttpClientModule),
    provideClientHydration(),
  ],
};

It is supposed that when the email and password are correct, it should send me a status code 200 indicating that everything is fine.

401 is a status code set by backend. the request is being sent. filters on your backend don't allow the query to pass through

It looks like the login endpoint is not public. You want to authenticate but you can't because the endpoint requires that you already are authenticated. That's BE stuff

Try adding withInterceptorsFromDi() to provideHttpClient() and remove
HttpClientModule import.
provideHttpClient(withFetch(), withInterceptorsFromDi()),

